# Multiple results for one row PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a data frame with Names and departments. All these Names can map to 4 different departments(Department A, B, C, and D). For example, each name has to get mapped to Department A, B, C, D. In the initial data, each name is only mapped to one department. In the final dataset, each name maps to four different departments.
I need a way to insert 3 additional rows for each name and also add the 3 other departments for them.

Example:

Initial Data:

```
Name Department
Joe  A
Ellen A
Zach  A
```

Final Data:

```
Name Department
Joe  A
Joe  B
Joe  C
Joe  D
Ellen A
Ellen B
Ellen C
Ellen D
Zach  A
Zach  B
Zach  C
Zach  D
```

I know this can be done in a for loop of some sort but I am very new in Pandas any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to assign to each name all departments as a list and then `.explode`:

```py
df = df.assign(Department=[["A", "B", "C", "D"]] * len(df)).explode(
    "Department"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Name Department
0    Joe          A
0    Joe          B
0    Joe          C
0    Joe          D
1  Ellen          A
1  Ellen          B
1  Ellen          C
1  Ellen          D
2   Zach          A
2   Zach          B
2   Zach          C
2   Zach          D
```

Comment: Turns out to be complicated to set a list as scalar like value, isn't it (?) Hence your by-`len(df)` repetition I guess.

Comment: @keepAlive Yes, I want to set to each row the list `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`, that's why I use `len(df)`. Then I `.explode()` this column to create new rows.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming just the `product` of values is needed [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) has much less overhead than `pandas` functions:

```
from itertools import product

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Joe', 'Ellen', 'Zach'],
                   'Department': ['A', 'A', 'A']})
```

Compute new DataFrame from [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(product(df['Name'].unique(),
                          ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
                  columns=df.columns)
```

`df`:

```
     Name Department
0     Joe          A
1     Joe          B
2     Joe          C
3     Joe          D
4   Ellen          A
5   Ellen          B
6   Ellen          C
7   Ellen          D
8    Zach          A
9    Zach          B
10   Zach          C
11   Zach          D
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
>>> departments = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda _, L=departments: L).explode().to_frame('Department')
      Department
Name            
Ellen          A
Ellen          B
Ellen          C
Ellen          D
Joe            A
Joe            B
Joe            C
Joe            D
Zach           A
Zach           B
Zach           C
Zach           D
```

---

Or [`pd.Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) has a `name` argument: convenient in such configuration:

```
>>> df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda _, L=departments: L).explode().reset_index(name='Department')
     Name Department
0   Ellen          A
1   Ellen          B
2   Ellen          C
3   Ellen          D
4     Joe          A
5     Joe          B
6     Joe          C
7     Joe          D
8    Zach          A
9    Zach          B
10   Zach          C
11   Zach          D
```

Comment: We may wonder why default to `departments` (instead of requesting the parent scope) ? Because it makes things go faster, which assertion can be checked using [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). To convince yourself, try `import dis; a=1; dis.dis(lambda _: a); dis.dis(lambda _, v=a: v)`. We have `LOAD_GLOBAL` in the first case, while we have a `LOAD_FAST` in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

We do `merge`

```
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'New Dept':list('ABCD')}),how='cross')
Out[373]: 
     Name Department New Dept
0     Joe          A        A
1     Joe          A        B
2     Joe          A        C
3     Joe          A        D
4   Ellen          A        A
5   Ellen          A        B
6   Ellen          A        C
7   Ellen          A        D
8    Zach          A        A
9    Zach          A        B
10   Zach          A        C
11   Zach          A        D
```